# Save WhenEvent result in a table

Tags: differential-equations, list-manipulation, parametric-functions

I have a set of coupled differential equations of functions which evolve (increase) monotonically:

```
NDSolve[{a'[t]=...,b'[t]=...,c'[t]=..., a[0]=a0, b[0]=b0, c[0]=c0},{a,b,c},{t,0,10}, 
Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> a[t] == 1, "EventAction" :-> Print[t,b[t],c[t]]}]
```

is giving me what I want for any particular choice of a0, b0, c0, i.e. the values of t (let's call it t-threshhold), b, c when a[t] = 1.

What I want to do is scan across a range of {amin, amax, astep}, {bmin, bmax, bstep}, {cmin, cmax, cstep} and **store** the results.

Eventually I would like to generate a table of a0, b0, c0, and t-threshhold values.

Any idea on how I could do this? I am essentially struggling with meaningfully storing the result of the WhenEvent condition, and with scanning across initial values in NDSolve. Note that there are poles in a, b, c depending on the initial values, I want the solver to ignore this (to give me the t-threshhold value and then stop calculation at the t=tpole before moving on to the next set of initial conditions)

Comment: Instead of printing the results, use `Sow` and `Reap`. For instance: replace your EventAction with `"EventAction" :> Sow[{t, b[t], c[t]}]`, and add a `Reap` at the top, i.e. `results = Reap@NDSolve[...]`. Look up their usage in the docs to clarify, and see this tutorial: [Collecting Expressions during Evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CollectingExpressionsDuringEvaluation.html).

Comment: @MarcoB - I have been able to use Sow and Reap with chosen initial conditions, however, I am still struggling with automatically "scanning" across initial conditions from a list {{a0,b0,c0},{a1,b1,c1},...}. Any suggestions on that? ParametericNDSolve hasn't been working for me and I also have a problem with the poles, and how to define a separate WhenEvent to stop integration when they occur

Comment: Sarah, you should be able to take `Sow` and `Reap` techniques from this question, and combine them with the pure-function approach I gave you in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174782/27951) to your previous similar question. It seems to me that the problem of mapping over a list of initial conditions is solved there. If not, please provide a *specific* example of what does not work (i.e. complete equations; it can be a made-up system, but something that we can run).